# Content block overlay fade in/out on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm stumped on a problem with overlay fading in and out to cover a block generated by some JS code.

Below is the link to the work. If you click on any of the continents, a bunch of blocks with the country flags will be generated. You'll also see the gray bar that says "some content". Ideally, I want that bar to be hidden, until I click on one of the flags. At which point, the overlay would slide in over the flag. Then when I click elsewhere outside the block, the overlay would slide out and disappear.

[CodePen link.](http://codepen.io/yzchen/pen/EWdepv)

I tried to set:

```
&__block-overlay {
  ....
  opacity: 0;
  ....
}
```

and

```
&__block-overlay:active {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

But it didn't work.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two issues to solve here. The first is the hiding of the 'Some Content' bars. You can achieve that by setting `overflow: hidden` on their parent, so that they are only visible when over the flag:

```
&__block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0.5%;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden; /* add this */
```

Then, to toggle the content visibility on successive clicks, use `toggleClass()` instead of `addClass()`:

```
blockClicked(e) {
  const $block = $(e.target.closest('.js-block'));
  $('.details-open').removeClass('details-open');
  $block.toggleClass('details-open');
},
```

[**Updated CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zZmmxp)

Comment: oh excellent. THANK YOU! 

Follow up question: how would I only have the most recently clicked overlay open? In other words, how do I hide all other overlays when a new one is clicked?

Comment: You could do that by removing the `.details-open` class from all other elements before adding it to the clicked one. I updated my answer for you

Comment: Ah, I was thinking along the lines of finding all the details-open and then toggling them all close, then toggle the current one open. I guess yours is more concise. MUCH APPRECIATED!

Comment: Absolutely! Thanks again!